# KNearestNeighbour is not running in multithread in Scikit-Learn

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm succesfully using scikit-learn on my machine. I'm experimenting with an anaconda implemnetation (that relies on MKL for multithreading) and an openblas implementation.

I'd really like to use a parallel version of k-nearest neighbour classifier, and according to https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4009 , sklearn should have merged this changes 1 year ago, in version 0.17.

Multithreading works successfully for PCA, and all numpy operations. I can tell multithreading is working due to high number of threads I can see when I do dot products and PCA. When I lunch KNN is taking around 10 minutes.
I’m classifying a high dimensional dataset of MNIST (image digits). So I’m doing PCA to get vector of dimension 35-50, and then I’m doing a nonlinear expansion, so I’m getting vector of dimension 600-100. That’s why I need parallelism so badly.

My version of sklearn is:

> print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.**version**))
>   The scikit-learn version is 0.18.1.

I'm using python3 and this is a sample of the code:

```
def classify_knn(train, test, train_labels):
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='ball_tree')
    clf = clf.fit(train, train_labels)
    return clf.predict(test)
```

I've tried with and without 'ball_tree'. No one should using python 2.7 in 2017 and neither do I.

Comment: So how do you know its not working?

Comment: That's simple: I see only one thread running. And it's take polynomially more time as I increase the dimension of the data. (not the number of points)

Comment: Can you give us more details about what you tried. you use python ? version ? joblib.Parallel ? Can you show us your code, like a basic implementation you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: Sure. I'm using python. It's really 3 lines of code for using KNN in scikit-learn, so I though it won't be much of an help to write them...

Comment: The last comment in the issue you posted suggests that the "Multiprocessing doesn't work in Python 2 due to BallTree pickling issues". Are you using python 2  or 3?

Comment: I'm using python 3.6 with scikit based on openblas and python 3.4 using python MKL in anaconda. None should use python 2 in 2017 :D

Comment: The reason I ask your code is because there is some option to set. As you can see in the documentation here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html n_jobs option is set to 1 by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just passing as a parameter

> n_jobs = -1

solved the issue.

Comment: Oh we find it at the same time ^^ Since the solution was in the documentation I don't know if it contribute a lot to SO but you can add link to the documentation and quote the use of this parameters in your answer

Comment: It's my fault. I didn't read the documentation because I assumed a multitthreading behaviour by default, as is happening with other API of scikit learn...